# Filtered content appears in the excerpt

Tags: plugins, content, excerpt, filters

I am modifying the content using the "the_content" filter. But this filtering is seen in the excerpts also.

Consider the following code,

```
function modify_content($content = ''){
    return 'HELLO ALL' . $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'modify_content');
```

This works in the main content perfectly.

---

[image: Filter content in the main post]

---

### But,

if you see in the excerpt, the "HELLO ALL" text is printed, which is unwanted.
[image]

---

How to avoid or remove the text in the excerpt ??? which is to be added only to the main content ?? I tried changing the priority but it is no use..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no manual excerpts added to the Post, Wordpress picks the content itself as excerpt for that Post. You may either put the excerpts for Posts manually or apply_filter('the_excerpt', 'modify_excerpt') and remove the unwanted text from the excerpt. The function code-structure will remain almost the same, with the exception that now you will want to remove the "Hello All" from excerpt.

I hope this helps; let us know if this resolves your issue.

Cheers,

Ruturaaj.

Comment: thanks for the idea. since I am in plugin development, a solid idea will be  very useful.